# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fineUploader' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, requirejs, fine-uploader

What am I am doing wrong here? I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with Knockout.js & Require.js.

Here is all the javascript files:

### app.contracts.js

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "../../Scripts/app/administrator",
    "paths": {
        "app.contracts": "app.contracts",
        "ko": "../../lib/knockout-2.2.1",        
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",
        "toastr": "../../lib/toastr",
        "moment": "../../lib/moment",
        "fineuploader": "../../lib/jquery.fineuploader-3.8.0",
        "model.contract": "../models/model.contract",
        "model.paymentterm": "../models/model.paymentterm",
        'knockout.bindings': "../../lib/knockout.bindings",
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
require(["main.contracts"], function (bs) { bs.run(); });
```

### knockout.bindings.js

```
define('knockout.bindings', ['ko', 'moment', 'fineuploader'], function (ko, moment, fineuploader) {
    ko.utils.contains = function (string, startsWith) {
        string = string || "";
        if (startsWith.length > string.length) return false;

        return string.toLowerCase().indexOf(startsWith.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var date = moment(value());
            var strDate = date.format('LL');
            $(element).text(strDate);
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.contractuploader = {
        console.log(fineuploader); // this is undefined
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            $(element).fineUploader({
                request: { endpoint: '/api/file', params: valueAccessor() },
                deleteFile: { enabled: true, endpoint: '/api/file' }
            })
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
            // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
            // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        }
    };

});
```

### main.contracts.js

```
define(['ko', 'contractsViewModel', 'model.contract', 'model.paymentterm', 'fineuploader'], function (ko, contractsViewModel, Contract, PaymentTerm, fineuploader) {
    var
        run = function () {

            var vm = new contractsViewModel();

            var array = [];

            var parts = document.location.href.split("/");
            var id = parts[parts.length - 1];

            vm.clientId(id);

            var ptArray = [];

            $.getJSON("/api/Clients/GetByClientId/" + vm.clientId(), function (data) {
                vm.clientName(data.Name);
                var newItem = {};
                newItem.Text = data.BusinessName;
                newItem.Value = true;
                vm.ownerTypes.push(newItem);
            });

            $.getJSON("/api/Companies/GetMyCompany", function (data) {
                var newItem = {};
                newItem.Text = data.Name;
                newItem.Value = false;
                vm.ownerTypes.push(newItem);
            });

            $.getJSON("/api/paymentterms/", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    var c = new PaymentTerm();
                    c.PaymentTermId(val.PaymentTermId);
                    c.Name(val.Name);
                    c.IsActive(val.IsActive);
                    ptArray.push(c);
                });
            }).then(function () {
                vm.paymentTerms(ptArray);

                var contractArray = [];
                $.getJSON("/api/Contracts/getbyclientId/" + vm.clientId(), function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        var c = new Contract();
                        c.ContractId(val.ContractId);
                        c.IsActive(val.IsActive);                            
                        contractArray.push(c);
                    });

                }).done(function () {
                    vm.contracts(contractArray);
                });
            });

            ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('#administrator-contracts-view'));
        };
    return {
        run: run
    };
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contracts";
}

@section scripts{

    <script data-main="../../Scripts/app/administrator/app.contracts" src="../../Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockoutjs")
}

<div id="administrator-contracts-view">
    <div class="contentList fullWidth">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: filteredContracts">
        <li data-bind="css: { 'edit': IsEditMode() }">
            <div class="floatL docs">
                <h3>Documents:</h3>
                <div class="docDisplay">
                    <a title="Add documents" id="docAddHref" data-bind="contractuploader: { fileSystemId: 1 }" href="#" class="docAdd"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="docIcon pdf">Doc Name</a>
                    <a href="" class="docIcon docx">Doc Name</a>
                    <a href="" class="docIcon xls">Doc Name</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.docDisplay -->
            </div>
           </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.contentList -->
</div>
<!-- /#administrator-contracts-view -->
```

Comment: What happens if you `console.log($(element))`?

Comment: You're not posting any console logs, and you're leaving out your link tags.  We'll need all of that.  This problem is likely easily solvable, but not if you don't include all of your code, including HTML.  I can only guess that you simply aren't including the proper libraries in your document.

Comment: console.log($(element)) = [a#docAddHref.docAdd, context: a#docAddHref.docAdd, jquery: "2.0.0", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
 So it is finding the element. I will look at providing more information.

Comment: I'm looking for the contents of your console: error messages, stack traces, etc.  The problem is likely with your markup.

Comment: Its seems like the fineuploader in knockout.bindings.js is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I need to included the jquery.fineuploader in the html file like this:

```
@section scripts{

    <script data-main="../../Scripts/app/administrator/app.contracts" src="../../Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockoutjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fineuploader")
}
```

This resolved the errors.